# Ruby read file line issue

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to read a file into a string. For instance, I tried reading this file:

```
123456  
23456  
3456  
456  
56  
6
```

I tried:

```
contents = File.open("test.txt", "rb").read  
print contents
```

---

```
IO.foreach('test.txt') do |line|  
  print line  
end
```

---

```
File.open('test.txt', 'r').each_line do |line|
  print line
end
```

but I seem to get a single line that will overwrite it's contents with each new line. I get `666666`.

Comment: For the first method, don't you need parentheses after the method? `File.open("...","rb").read()`

Comment: I suspect the issue is with the text file, as all of these should give you the output you are looking for.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to be the fact that the file is using the CR line terminator (or your terminal is messed up and not responding to LF). `print` does not go into the new line by default (you should use `puts` if that's what you want), and `each_line` does not strip the line terminator. So what happens is, `print "123456\r`" prints out `123456` and then returns the cursor to the start of the line, without moving to the next line (so the cursor is on `1`. Then when you `print "23456\r"`, it will overwrite the first five characters and again come back to the start, the current state being `234566`... In the end, `566666` will get overwritten by `"6\r"` for the final `666666`.

Comment: Thank you, the text file indeed only had carriage returns.

Answer (score 1):

**Why not try the simple solution**

```
# ruby sample code.
# process every line in a text file with ruby (version 1).
file='test.txt'
File.readlines(file).each do |line|
  puts line
end
```

**Second approach**

```
# ruby sample code.
# process every line in a text file with ruby (version 2).
file='test.txt'
f = File.open(file, "r")
f.each_line { |line|
  puts line
}
f.close
```

[Answer Source](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/ruby/how-process-line-text-file-ruby)